# How to pass the request code to onSearchRequested like startForActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to pass a request code to a searchable activity, like `startActivityForResult`. But `onSearchRequested` and `startSearch` cannot be passed it. In below example, I assume that after pressing a menu icon, a Search dialog will be shown at the top of window and I will send the request code and query to the searchable activity.

```
private static final int SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
    case SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE:
        // Something to do after finishing the searchable activity

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // ...

    case 2:
        onSearchRequested(); // I want to pass SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE here!
        return true;

    // ...
    }
}
```

I have read a tutorial of Search Interface in API Guides ( https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html ) and the API reference. But, I cannot find out how to do this.